# What is logical way to calculate percentage error?

Tags: experimental-physics, error-analysis

I wish to know logic behind percentage error formula.

Say, $A$ is measured or calculated quantity, $B$ is theoretical or known or benchmark quantity. Then, what should be the formula for percentage error?

$$
\frac{(A-B)}{A}. 100
$$

or

$$
\frac{(A-B)}{B}. 100
$$

or should we have $(B-A) $ in above expressions? I believe percentage error has to do something 'with respect to original quantity' so we might have $B$ in the denominator.

Can someone explain what is correct way and more importantly, why?

Comment: Percent error is almost never of interest, so the real answer is that working scientists would never worry about this issue. If you're testing an experiment against theory, there's no way to know whether a 0.03% difference is consistent with the theory or inconsistent with it, because it depends on how much error would have been *expected* due to the inherent precision of the technique. In real science we would say we measured A=____$\pm$____, and compared with the predicted value B=____ this was off by, e.g., 5.7 std dev, which is highly statistically significant, so the theory is disproved.

Comment: The place where working scientists bother with fractional error is in comparing the size of uncertainties: *"neglecting the foo asymmetry is about a 2% error, and we're looking at about 5% counting error anyway so I think it is OK."*

Comment: @BenCrowell `Percent error is almost never of interest` Why so? If I want to measure millimeter dimension with an instrument with micron resolution. I would certainly specify tolerance as my measuring device will have inherent inaccuracy. However, when I deal with nominal measurement, not the upper or lower limits, I would certainly say my nominal dimension has so much %error. I believe this practice is followed by many practicing metrologists.

Comment: It's not of interest outside of teaching laboratories because there is a built in assumption that the right answer is known. Only, we're doing science and trying to learn something *new* (again once you get beyond leaning exercises in school). Real science has to find a way to quantify precision and uncertainty without reference to a predetermined correct value.

Answer (score 1):

It would actually be neither. Percentage is *always* positive, so we invoke absolute value to get
$$E=\frac{|A-B|}{B}\times 100$$
Actually, we can also use
$$E=\frac{|B-A|}{B}\times 100$$
Percent error is always taken with respect to the known quantity because it is important to know how far off the *measurement* is from the known value, and not vice versa - i.e. what percent of the known value the measurement is off by. Why do we care? Well, *this way, we can compare percent errors of two measurements of a quantity that already has a known value.*

Comment: I disagree on both counts. There is no particular reason to prefer division by A or by B in general, and it is not true that we don't care about the sign. As an example where you would certainly not want to divide by $B$, there could be a case where you're testing a theoretical prediction that $B=0$.

Comment: @BenCrowell So you would divide by $A$? You're certainly right that dividing by $0$ would mean that dividing by $B$ would be pointless, but I've always learned that you divide by $B$. Also, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_error) (not the best source, I know) and [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RelativeError.html) indicate division by $B$,as does [this page](http://groups.molbiosci.northwestern.edu/holmgren/Glossary/Definitions/Def-P/percent_error.html).

Comment: @BenCrowell I know from your profile that you were an experimentalist, and so I would typically defer to you in matters like this, but it seems like this is for an introductory-level physics question - and this is how I've seen it taught in introductory-level physics.

Comment: Assuming that you are going to compute this thing at all, the sign carries useful information. But you certainly don't compute it in the case of an expected value of zero---that case always calls for careful treatment.

Comment: true, this is a convention one **measures a relative error with respect to sth** either $B$ or $A$, the final result is not of such importance since one can always express one result in terms of the other, however the explanation given that one can use the known (or expected or previous) quantity as the base, seems good